# Func Delegate in Web API referencing method in different project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, delegates

I'm currently working on an .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. I need to send data via C# to a Web API, alter the data in a PUT method in the API and return it.

So far so good, the only issue is my architecture: The Web API is project type Class Library and will be started from a different Project in a different Solution (My server), which has the logic (a specific calculation) in it, encapsulated in a method. Somehow, I need to send (delegate) the method from the starting project (my server) to the API Project and use it in the PUT method.

My solution structure looks like that, I cannot change it:

Solution 1:
+ Client (Console, C#)
+ Web API (Class Library, C#) => needs to be in this project, because it is only necessary for Solution 1, I cannot put the API in Solution 2.

Solution 2:
+ Server with Logic (Console, C#) => the project including logic is in a different solution.

**Solution 1: Client**, works fine, I just call the API with an HTTPClient in C#.

**Solution 1: Web API Controller:**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int aFromClient)
    {
        // action delegate to method from my Server to manipulate data
        Func<int, int, int> func = SumMethodFromServer;

        int b = 4;

        int result = func(aFromClient, b);

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Server with custom logic:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress)); // I thought maybe, I can pass the method on this position somehow as a custom middleware, hmm

    }

    // Somehow pass this method as a delegate to the Web Api...
    static int SumMethodFromServer(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can pass a custom method to a Web API as a delegate from a different project, in a different Solution?

If there would be a way without Dependency Injection, this would be advantageous, but I think it will be impossible without? :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Your Server looks a lot like a Client. And I can't tell how you are hosting your API.

Comment: The problem seems to be about circular dependencies, not totally clear. Why is `SumMethodFromServer` on the server?

Comment: "So far so good, the only issue is my architecture" made me laugh.

Comment: haha yes, it's a bit tricky - I need to host the API in a different Solution due to rational reasons.

Comment: and yes, my "server" is kind of a test client. It starts the API from the class library. The Startup class is linked.

Comment: It is not possible for a web server to call a method on the client. That would be a massive security hole. You will need to either copy and paste the method or expose it somehow, perhaps as a web service of its own.

Comment: good point, thank you John Wu.

Comment: What about Custom Middleware? I think I can configure my API with Middleware using the IAppBuilder interface, but I'm not sure if i can use it within the API itself.

Comment: Hi, it's actually possible :) ...the solution is called: HTTPMessageHandler. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: Well, I kinda doubt that middleware is the answer but do post a self-answer. Or delete the question.